# How long does it take for Steam to re-fill product key stock?

Tags: steam

With the recent steam sales, I bought a game that was -50% (GTA V).

When it finished downloading, I tried to launch it for the first time, but I had an error message saying they were **out of stock for product keys on this item** (I can copy-paste the message, but it's in french).

Has anyone ever encountered this ? How long does it normally take for them to replenish their stock ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steam is only allowed to distribute the amount of keys they have being authorized to distribute from Rockstar due to this you got the **out of stock for product keys on this item**. No information online from Steam actually states how long it will take so the information from forums should be taken with a grain of salt:

> Took Steam 3-5 days if I recall to send the first key
>
> [(Source)](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/yes-it-is-possible-for-steam-to-run-out-of-stock.236302/)

I would say wait a two/three days and then consult support if it does not start working.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll post another comment as soon as I get the key, so people may know how long it took for me. I did not have any warning regarding this before I bought it, that's kind of lame from Steam ..

Comment: Just as an update : I still do not have a product key, but according to [Valve](https://steamcommunity.com/app/271590/discussions/0/1778262124930115732/?ctp=2#c1778262124930468369) it seems to be an internal problem